# How to get appended HTML to the consoles log?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, append

This might be stupid question, but...
Question: How to get the appended HTML to the console's log? I am 100 % sure that my appended HTML is broken and for future purposes I would like to know how to get the result to log? I am trying to implement small software for Android using Jquery Mobile and Phonegap.

Of course you can check my function too, because appends are not correct at the moment.

EDIT: QUESTION 2:

Could you find the reason why I can't see the text PÖÖ/POO. So the second TR is totally missing, but why?

```
function populateTable(){
        console.log("###########populateTable()#############");
        $("#table").find('tbody')
        .append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>')
                .append($('<img>')
                    .attr('src', 'images/cart_1.jpg')
                    .text('Image cell')
                )
                .append($('</td>')))
         .append($('</tr>'))

            .append($('<tr>')
                    .append($('<td>')
                        .append($('PÖÖ'))
                     .append($('</td>'))
            .append($('</tr>'))
            )));




        var strinki = JSON.stringify($("#table"));

        console.log("2....*******************>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" +strinki);
    }
```

Comment: how about `console.log($('#table'));`

Comment: Your code is broken because you are doing stuff you can't do, such as trying to convert a standalone end tag to a DOM element.

Comment: `var strinki = $("#table").html();` ?

Comment: That was it :) It was so simple that I should know that by meself :)    var strinki = $("#table").html();

Comment: 08-31 19:45:55.939: I/Web Console(5250):   <tr><td><img src="images/cart_1.jpg"></img></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></tbody> The second <TR> is missing, but why?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is `console.log($('#table')[0])` so you get the DOM element.

If you prefer a HTML string because you are using a browser with inferior debug tools (in Firebug I can easily view a DOM subtree): `console.log($('#table').html())`

Comment: This returns: [object HTMLTableElement] and I just needed the HTML-code. Thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 0):

That was it :) It was so simple that I should know that by meself :)

```
var strinki = $("#table").html();
```